# jQuery trigger - how to pass to handler information about how triggered the event

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I wan to do something like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.someclass',function(){
   $('.otherclass').trigger('keyup',{aField:'my data'});
});

$(document).on('keyup','.otherclass',function(e){
   console.log(e.aField); // and to have printed 'my data'
});
```

I want to know if there is a way to do something similar, but to work. Because like that it doesn't work.

---

Maybe the example is not very clear: When I click on a link, I want to trigger `keyup` event on a `input`, but also I want to pass an object `{aField:'my data'}` when triggering it.

---

Anyway got it by myself already.
The solution was to add one more parameter `object` to the handler

```
$(document).on('keyup','.otherclass',function(e,object){
    console.log(object.aField); // this printed 'my data'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer

```
$(document).on('click','.someclass',function(){
   $('.otherclass').trigger('keyup',{aField:'my data'});
});

$(document).on('keyup','.otherclass',function(e, obj){
   console.log(obj.afield); // and to have printed 'my data'
});
```

This is the correct way of passing arguments to an event via trigger, full documentation available here http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

*Update:* Why not use a common handler for both instances instead of trying to trigger something.

```
function handleInputAction(data) {
  console.log(data.aField)
}

$(document).on('click','.someclass',function(){
   handleInputAction({aField:'my data'});
});

$(document).on('keyup','.otherclass',function(e){
   handleInputAction(e.aField);
});
```

Use either `$(this)` or the event target.

```
$(document).on('keyup','.otherclass',function(e){
  console.log($(this).attr('aField'));
  // or
  console.log(e.currentTarget.aField);
  // or
  console.log($(e.currentTarget).attr('aField'));
});
```

Comment: the event target is the "input" but i need to access somehow the object {aField:'my data'} that i pass when triggering the event manualy.